# A SearchPattern contain multiple search pattern in SevenZipSharp

Tags: c#, sevenzipsharp

I use `SevenZipSharp` to compress my files and directories.

I use the following code and it works well:

```
var searchPattern = "*.txt";
compressor.CompressDirectory(directory, archiveName, password, searchPattern, recursion);
```

Now, i want filter the directory files by a more complicated SearchPattern like this:

```
var searchPattern = "*.txt && *.xml";
compressor.CompressDirectory(directory, archiveName, password, searchPattern, recursion);
```

In this case i get:

> Index was outside the bounds of the array

Is there a way to do this by `SearchPattern`?
If NO, How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no, you can't do this with `SearchPattern`.

---

As you can see in the source code [here](http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#SevenZip/SevenZipCompressor.cs):

```
public void CompressDirectory(
            string directory, Stream archiveStream,
            string password = "", string searchPattern = "*", bool recursion = true)
        {
        ...
#if CS4
            files.AddRange((new DirectoryInfo(directory)).GetFiles(searchPattern).Select(fi => fi.FullName));
#else
            foreach (FileInfo fi in (new DirectoryInfo(directory)).GetFiles(searchPattern))
            {
                files.Add(fi.FullName);
            }
#endif
        ...
        }
```

Internally, SevenZipSharp calls [Directory.GetFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which doesn't support multiple masks.

---

So you have several alternatives:

- Compress the extensions one by one (creating the archive the first time, and then adding the files to the directory)
- Create another overload managing several extensions (regex?) and contribute to the project